# Insert Sponsor logo in custom own theme

Tags: plugins, images

I'm new to wordpress.
I'm creating my own theme. There is a sponsor logo area in my theme.
For that case I'm going to use [cr3ativ sponsor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cr3ativ-sponsor/).
I have installed the plugin and added the sponsors logo.

How I have to insert the PHP code for that sponsor plugin.

I read the documentation and found like below.

```
[sponsor_level category="all" orderby="menu_order" columns="4" image="yes" title="no" link="yes" bio="yes" show="9999999"]
```

Do I need to insert into my php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a shortcode, it's meant to go in content. If you want to output it in a template but don't know the underlying function then you can use `do_shortcode()`:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[sponsor_level category="all" orderby="menu_order" columns="4" image="yes" title="no" link="yes" bio="yes" show="9999999"]' ); ?>
```

Comment: How I suppose to add class for each image.

Comment: The plugin would have to give you a way to do that.